# Vue.js: typescript doesn't recognize mixin data in component

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I've searched around but couldn't really find an answer.

I'm getting an error from Typescript saying that the property doesn't exist, when it actually exists in the mixin included in the component.

**MyMixin.ts**

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export const myMixin = Vue.mixin({
  computed: {
    someComputedData: function() {
       return 'This is my computed data';
    }
  }
});
```

**MyComponent.vue**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { myMixin } from '../mixins/MyMixin';

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'MyComponent',
  mixins: [myMixin],
  methods: {
    someMethod: function() {
      this.someComputedData // <<< Typescript complains that this property doesn't exist
    }
  }
});
```

Versions:

- typescript 3.5.3
- vue 2.6.10
- vue-template-compiler 2.6.10

Comment: `mixins` are not heavily supportive in `vue-typesccript` because `vue-class-component` dependency. I once tried with this https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-mixin-decorator But didn't went far

Comment: Yeah I've tried both `vue-mixin-decorator` and `vue-typed-mixins`, no luck. Apparently mixins and typescript only work in class components. Reason why I'm not using class component is because in Vue 3 they will drop it in favor of functional components.

Comment: Since you're preparing for Vue 3 anyway, it might be better to avoid mixins altogether and use the composition API.